# Why this group.wait always succeeds?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to get timeout from group.wait but this is always succeeds.

```
blueGroup.enter()
for i in 1...1000000 {
    print(i)
}
blueGroup.leave()

let time: DispatchTime = .now() + .seconds(1)
let result = blueGroup.wait(timeout: time)

print("finished \(result)") // always success


let redGroup = DispatchGroup()
redGroup.enter()
for i in 0...300000 {
    print(i / (i + 1))
    if i == 300000 {
        print(i)
        let result = redGroup.wait(timeout: .now() + .seconds(10))
        print(result)  // always timeout
        redGroup.leave()
    }
}
```

Where I'am wrong?

thank you

Comment: Why do you expect the wait to fail or timeout?

Comment: @rmaddy i want to get timeout.

Comment: You need code that calls wait before calling leave.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you. this is new idea to test out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
blueGroup.enter()   // Now the Blue Group will block waiters
for i in 1...1000000 {
   print(i)
}
blueGroup.leave()  // Blue group leaves match enters, so no blocking

let time: DispatchTime = .now() + 0.001
print(time)    
let result = blueGroup.wait(timeout: time) // Nothing blocking, so moving on

print("finished \(result)") // finished success (as expected)
```

If you're not done with the group, don't leave it.

Comment: So I should do some condition and then leave, right and otherwise every time I have success?

Comment: You should leave the group when you want waiters to not block any more. It's very unclear what you're doing. Dispatch groups make no sense unless there is some concurrency. You're doing everything on a single queue. What do you want the dispatch group to do?

Comment: I'm just testing how groups work. So trying to figure out how to work with .wait method.

Comment: See the Concurrency Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25